# Pausing Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactional-replication

**Scenario:**

I'm working with a customer that has a live database. On a separate server, they have a copy of this database and they have transactional replication setup, which runs constantly. I have an SSIS package that runs on the copy of the database for up to an hour to export data to a reporting database.

When I've tested the package with replication enabled, it occasionally fails as it reads from various tables at different points of the execution. The problem is that if some data is read at an early stage, which subsequently gets deleted/inserted, other related records that are read later on effectively become orphaned and cause lookup failures. Whilst I have various safeguards to combat this, it's difficult to cater for every case as not all records have dates that I can use to limit data.

**Plan:**

I have been looking at pausing the replication job, so that the package can run with static data and then re-enable it once the package has run. Once the replication is enabled again, all of the transactions from the live database that were generated during the package execution should then be applied to the copy.

**Problem:**

I've done some reading around the various [Replication Agents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152501.aspx) used for transactional replication, but I'm not entirely sure what the minimum requirement is for pausing the replication.

At the moment I'm looking at pausing the [Distribution Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147328.aspx) and the [Log Reader Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146878.aspx) to achieve what I want to do. The question is, do I need to pause both agent jobs or can I pause one or the other so that the transactions build up and are applied once the agent is enabled?

I'm not sure if some of this is dependent on specific configurations or setup, but I can provide further information if required, so please comment if more information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm not entirely sure what the minimum requirement is for pausing the replication.

Replication works like below

Log reader agent reads the transactional log from publisher and inserts those records in distributor DB and also marks those log as inactive(so that Tlog space can be reused)

Now Distributor DB reads those records  and inserts it into subscriber Database..

Now When you want to stop/pause  Replication,you can stop

1.Log reader agent
  Right click job and stop

or

2.Distributor agent
Right click job and stop

or

both

> The question is, do I need to pause both agent jobs or can I pause one or the other so that the transactions build up and are applied once the agent is enabled?

If you pause  only Distributor agent ( i would do the same),Log reader will do it's job  and also there will be no impact to Log reusabilty on publisher

there are also caveats like ,if replication latency xrosses maximum limit,you will need to reinitialize replication.Though this will be huge like 24 hours

You also can use below link to monitor replication,after it has been enabled

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/07/monitoring-sql-server-transactional-replication/

Comment: thanks for answering, so are you saying you would pause the Distributor agent only, and this will achieve what I'm after?

Comment: `Once the replication is enabled again, all of the transactions from the live database that were generated during the package execution should then be applied to the copy.` if this publisher,then i would recommend stopping both

Comment: Though i am not sure how these can occur `later on effectively become orphaned`,unless you are using no lock

Comment: An example, we read `users` at a certain point, so say 2 users exist at the start of the package, but then another user is added during the execution, one of the later steps reads all user information and links it back to the users that exist. But user 3 was not read in the earlier step so can't be looked up in the destination. This is one example, which I am aware could be coded around, but there are others.

Comment: what is the maximum time that you are willing to stop ?

Comment: i mean transactions per hour

Comment: the ssis package may run for up to an hour, depending on the number of records written, as it runs once nightly. the source database could generate a few thousand records during this period of time. It will be scheduled overnight where system use is at a minimum though, so it's likely to be far fewer records than at peak times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124978/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-tanner).